# JavaScript: How can I change property names of objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using this `react-select`: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select

The format for options data that they require is:

```
const options = [
    { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
    { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry'},
    { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
];
```

My array is set up differently as follows:

```
const columns = [
    { name: 'OrderNumber', title: 'Order Number' },
    { name: 'strawberry', title: 'Strawberry' },
    { name: 'vanilla', title: 'Vanilla' }
]
```

I am not able to change my array. If try to use `name` or `value` in my option items, I encounter issues using them with `select-react`. If I change my `name` to `value`, the select options are populating, however I don't want to do that.

Can anyone teach me how can I change my array's `name` to `value`?

Comment: Can't you transform your array and feed `react-select` somehow?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use the `.map()` function to make the data in `columns` suitable for use with `react-select`.

The `.map()` function is available on the `Array` type. It creates a new array from the array you call it on, and allows you to provide a function that transforms/changes each item as it is copied from the original array.

You can make use of it as follows:

```
const columns = [
    { name: 'OrderNumber', title: 'Order Number' },
    { name: 'strawberry', title: 'Strawberry' },
    { name: 'vanilla', title: 'Vanilla' }
]

const options = columns.map(function(row) {

   // This function defines the "mapping behaviour". name and title 
   // data from each "row" from your columns array is mapped to a 
   // corresponding item in the new "options" array

   return { value : row.name, label : row.title }
})

/*
options will now contain this:
[
    { value: 'OrderNumber', label: 'Order Number' },
    { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
    { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
];
*/
```

For more information, [see the MDN documentation for `.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 11):

If you just want to rename the `name` property to `value` you can use a `map` and destruct the `name` property as `value` and pick the rest.

```js
const columns = [
    { name: 'OrderNumber', title: 'Order Number' },
    { name: 'strawberry', title: 'Strawberry' },
    { name: 'vanilla', title: 'Vanilla' }
];

const newColumns = columns.map( item => {
  const { name: value, ...rest } = item;
  return { value, ...rest }
 }
);

console.log( newColumns );
```

But, I suspect that you would want this since `react-select` doesn't work (as far as I see) with `title`. It waits for a `label` prop I guess. If this is so, go with and change all the properties as @Dacre Denny suggested. I like arrow functions :) So:

```
const newColumns = columns.map( item =>
  ( { value: item.name, label: item.title } )
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `destructuring` with renaming property will simplify.

```js
const options = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" },
];

const columns = options.map(({ value: name, label: title }) => ({
  name,
  title,
}));

console.log(columns);
```