# Assign new properties to an array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of Objects

```
const options = [
 { id: 1, name: "Back Pain" },
 { id: 2, name: "Body aches" },
 { id: 3, name: "Cold Sores" },
 { id: 4, name: "Cough" },
 { id: 5, name: "Constipation" },
];
```

I am trying to write a function that will assign new properties to the object.

The output I am looking for is:

```
const options = [
 { value: 1, label: "Back Pain" },
 { value: 2, label: "Body aches" },
 { value: 3, label: "Cold Sores" },
 { value: 4, label: "Cough" },
 { value: 5, label: "Constipation" },
];
```

I have tried to loop through the array using a for loop, but can not figure it out. 
Thanks for the help:)

Comment: `data.map(({id:value, name:label})=>({value, label}))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: How can I change property names of objects in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52106582/javascript-how-can-i-change-property-names-of-objects-in-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
const data=[{ id: 1, name: "Back Pain" },
 { id: 2, name: "Body aches" },
 { id: 3, name: "Cold Sores" },
 { id: 4, name: "Cough" },
 { id: 5, name: "Constipation" },
];

var result = data.map(({id:value, name:label})=>({value, label}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please at least look for duplicates before answering...